# Changing count number on input line every time?

Tags: python, input

So I am writing a code and I want my input line to change the number with every guess. For example;

`Enter a letter for guess #1:`
(take input)

`Enter a letter for guess #2:` (take new input)

Is there a way I can change the number after the # every time?

My code right now is

`letterguess = input("Enter a letter for guess #")`

I know that the input line can only take one argument, so when I try to add a `, count` it doesnt work. I've tried to look up functions that can help but I'm getting stuck. Any advice helps! Thanks!

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python string format", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Answer (score 0):

If you put your code in a loop

```
count = 1
while True:
    letter_guess = input(f"Input a letter for guess #{count}")
     # do something ...
     count = count + 1
```

Comment: Note that f-strings are only available on Python 3.6+. There is no python-3.x tag, just python.

Answer (score 0):

you can try a for loop and place all the desired code inside it

```
for i in range(3):
letterguess = input(f"Enter a letter for guess {i}#")
```

where placing an f infront of a string makes it a formatted string that will let you put variables inside

Comment: Note that f-strings are only available on Python 3.6+. There is no python-3.x tag, just python.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `,count` you could format like this:

`letterguess = input("Enter a letter for guess #%d" % count)`